# Voting button shows arrow cursor not hand cursor

Tags: php, html, css

Working on the voting button on this page: http://www.audiobookreviews.com/genre.php

Now when the cursor is over it stays at the arrow but would like it to be the hand cursor.

I tried a few answers here but no luck (from here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden)

```
<input type="hidden" id="post_id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
<img src="Circle-icons-arrow-up.svg" id="udc" style="width:30px; height:30px;" onclick="up(<?php echo $id; ?>);">
<span style="font-size:16px;" id="upvalue<?php echo $id; ?>">
    <?php if($row1['vote_up']=='') { echo 0; } else{ echo $row1['vote_up']; } ?>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
:hover{
.grab {cursor: -webkit-grab; cursor: grab;}
}
```

Check https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp for more

Comment: It has all the list of cursor options that you can choose from. I just gave one example.

Answer (score 0):

This cloud should work

```
<td><input type="hidden" id="post_id" value="100"><img src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fcommons%2Fthumb%2F2%2F20%2FCircle-icons-arrow-up.svg%2F480px-Circle-icons-arrow-up.svg.png&amp;f=1" id="udc" style="width:30px; height:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="up(100);"> +<span style="font-size:16px;" id="upvalue100">7</span></td>
```

i only added

```
cursor:pointer
```

on style: copy the below code and paste it before the table

```
<style>
#udc{cursor:pointer}
</style>
```

however, your site is vulnerable for sql injection. you should fix it before making your site online